# Adding KSTokenView, fixed errors for Swift2, now getting a Segmentation Fault: 11

Tags: ios, swift, segmentation-fault, swift2, kstokenview

I added the KSTokenView project from GitHub: https://github.com/khawars/KSTokenView/ and fixed all of the errors that arose from switching to xcode 7 and swift 2. Now, when I try and build my project I get an error that says `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11`. How do I go about trying to fix an error like this? I've never encountered one before.

The stack is:

```
0  swift                    0x0000000104300edb llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 43
1  swift                    0x000000010430161b SignalHandler(int) + 379
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff9adeef1a _sigtramp + 26
3  swift                    0x00000001041a157e llvm::StringMap<llvm::Value*, llvm::MallocAllocator>::insert(std::__1::pair<llvm::StringRef, llvm::Value*>) + 142
4  swift                    0x000000010415bfdc llvm::StoreInst::StoreInst(llvm::Value*, llvm::Value*, bool, llvm::Instruction*) + 60
5  swift                    0x0000000103e57b44 llvm::IRBuilder<true, llvm::ConstantFolder, llvm::IRBuilderDefaultInserter<true> >::CreateStore(llvm::Value*, llvm::Value*, bool) + 68
6  swift                    0x0000000102506949 swift::irgen::SingleScalarTypeInfo<(anonymous namespace)::PrimitiveTypeInfo, swift::irgen::LoadableTypeInfo>::initialize(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, swift::irgen::Explosion&, swift::irgen::Address) const + 41
7  swift                    0x00000001024fa0bc swift::irgen::SequentialTypeInfo<(anonymous namespace)::LoadableStructTypeInfo, swift::irgen::LoadableTypeInfo, (anonymous namespace)::StructFieldInfo, true>::initialize(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, swift::irgen::Explosion&, swift::irgen::Address) const + 220
8  swift                    0x00000001024fa0bc swift::irgen::SequentialTypeInfo<(anonymous namespace)::LoadableStructTypeInfo, swift::irgen::LoadableTypeInfo, (anonymous namespace)::StructFieldInfo, true>::initialize(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, swift::irgen::Explosion&, swift::irgen::Address) const + 220
9  swift                    0x00000001024f89cc swift::irgen::SequentialTypeInfo<(anonymous namespace)::ClangRecordTypeInfo, swift::irgen::LoadableTypeInfo, (anonymous namespace)::ClangFieldInfo, true>::initialize(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, swift::irgen::Explosion&, swift::irgen::Address) const + 236
10 swift                    0x00000001024f89cc swift::irgen::SequentialTypeInfo<(anonymous namespace)::ClangRecordTypeInfo, swift::irgen::LoadableTypeInfo, (anonymous namespace)::ClangFieldInfo, true>::initialize(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, swift::irgen::Explosion&, swift::irgen::Address) const + 236
11 swift                    0x0000000102498c5f swift::irgen::CallEmission::setArgs(swift::irgen::Explosion&, llvm::ArrayRef<swift::SILParameterInfo>, swift::irgen::WitnessMetadata*) + 1775
12 swift                    0x00000001024c0f79 swift::irgen::emitObjCPartialApplication(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, swift::SILDeclRef, swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::SILFunctionType>, swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::SILFunctionType>, llvm::Value*, swift::SILType, swift::irgen::Explosion&) + 1945
13 swift                    0x000000010252eec4 swift::SILVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::IRGenSILFunction, void>::visit(swift::ValueBase*) + 32084
14 swift                    0x0000000102523c1d swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSILFunction(swift::SILFunction*) + 10973
15 swift                    0x000000010248b938 swift::irgen::IRGenModuleDispatcher::emitGlobalTopLevel() + 376
16 swift                    0x000000010250af39 performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 793
17 swift                    0x000000010250b3b0 swift::performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::SourceFile&, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, unsigned int) + 64
18 swift                    0x00000001024128a8 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&) + 13704
19 swift                    0x000000010240f10a frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 2682
20 swift                    0x000000010240b797 main + 2247
21 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff994545c9 start + 1
22 libdyld.dylib            0x000000000000004f start + 1723513479
```